# How to give accelerator key to keyboard backspace key

Tags: mfc

I am developing MFC dialog based application. my requirement is when user click on backspace it should be focused on Edit text control and delete text as normal backspace works.
this dialog has single edit box and multiple buttons, wherever currently focus on current dialog when user click on backspace, it should be focus on edit box and able to work as backspace key.

Comment: What does *"normal"* mean here? In a standard edit control, the backspace key has 2 distinct behaviors: `1` If part or all of the text is selected, remove the selected text. `2` Otherwise remove the character to the left of the caret (if any). When the dialog manager navigates to an edit control, it selects (by default) the entire text. Subsequently hitting the backspace key would thus result in removing the entire text. Is that the behavior you are looking for?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Do you have an accelerator resource which does not allow the edit control to perform its normal backspace processing, or the default behaviour (select the entire text on entering with the tab key, delete the selection if any, otherwise the character to the left) is not the desired one? Please clarify. The dialog when opened focuses on the first control in the tab order.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the key in an override of `PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)`:

```
BOOL MyDialog::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
    if (pMsg->message == WM_KEYDOWN &&
        pMsg->wParam == VK_BACK)
    {
        // do your thing here
        if (GetFocus() != &theEditBox)
            GotoDlgCtrl(&theEditBox);
    }
    return MyDialog::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```